# How to set the values dynamically to object in an array in ts

Tags: javascript

```
let a=[
    {'firstName':"iroman",
    'lastName':"k"},
    {'firstName':"antman",
    'lastName':"k"}
]
let b=[]
let co=[]
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    a['firstName']='hulk'
    b.push(a[i])
}
console.log('-----' + JSON.stringify(b))
```

I am not able to add the dynamic content to object. Thanks in advance

excepted outut:

```
[{"firstName":"hulk","lastName":"k"},{"firstName":"hulk","lastName":"k"}]

Actual output-
[{"firstName":"iroman","lastName":"k"},{"firstName":"antman","lastName":"k"}]:
```

Comment: you should do `a[i]['firstname']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
a[i]['firstName']='hulk';
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `a[i]`

```js
let a=[
    {'firstName':"iroman",
    'lastName':"k"},
    {'firstName':"antman",
    'lastName':"k"}
]
let b=[]
let co=[]
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    a[i]['firstName']='hulk'
    b.push(a[i])
}
console.log('-----' + JSON.stringify(b))
```

Using `map()`

```js
let a=[
    {'firstName':"iroman",
    'lastName':"k"},
    {'firstName':"antman",
    'lastName':"k"}
]

let b = a.map(i => (i.firstName = 'hulk', i))
console.log('-----' + JSON.stringify(b))
```